# Mouse glitching when hover on richtextbox in designer mode C# visual studio 2015/2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

So when I hover over my richtextbox the mouse starts switching between the regular cursor and the "resize-cursor" really quickly. I am also having problems with getting it's properties show up in the properties window.

When I run the application the textbox is working as it's supposed to do.
I've tried both with visual studio 2013 community, 2015 community, 2015 express for desktop. I've also reinstalled then several times.

Video showing the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdrrOaZo7BY
I apoligize for the bad video and the music (didn't find a no-music option).

EDIT: tried doing the same thing on another computer without any problems. Also tried with another mouse.

EDIT #2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a RTB subclass? If so, do show us the code!

Comment: @TaW It was a blank project when the video started but I'll update with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now resolved so I thought I'll share the "solution".

The problem was caused by Kaspersky Internet Security. (Note: I've seen other people confirming this on other sites).

Since the question was asked I have now updated to Windows 10 and therefore updated Kaspersky Internet Security to a newer and Windows 10 compatible version, in which the problem has been resolved.